# Call lua in response to 503 in haproxy

Tags: lua, haproxy

I'm using the HAProxy Lua API. I would like to call Lua actions on *all* http-request and http-response events.

This works fine except when HAProxy itself cannot complete the request (eg no backend available). In that case, I cannot find a way to call Lua.

eg

```
listen appname
    bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    mode http
    http-request lua.handle-request
    http-response lua.handle-response
    server hostname 127.0.0.1:8001 check
```

This works fine, and `handle-request` and `handle-response` are called, even if the backend server returns a `500` status or other error.

However if HAProxy itself cannot find the backend (returning a 503 itself), then `handle-request` is called, but not `handle-response`.

I've tried using the TCP actions, too.

Is there any way to run Lua code in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find to do this was an utterly terrible and evil hack that should never be used.

Use a `task` to read UDP from syslog to capture the 503 responses from the HAproxy logs.

Config:

```
lua-load youre_a_terrible_person.lua
log 127.0.0.1:8004 local0 debug
option httplog
```

Lua:

```lua
core.register_task(function()
  local socket = require("socket")

  udp = socket.udp()
  udp:setsockname("*", 8004)
  udp:settimeout(0)

  while true do
      data = udp:receive()
      if data then
          print("Received: ", data)
          -- Look for your 503 and do stuff
      else
        core.sleep(1)
      end
      core.yield()
  end
end)
```

Again, cannot stress enough how much of a bad idea this is.